# Spring SFTP Adapter InboundAdapter with RotatingServerAdvice - Getting full path

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

**Using spring-integration-sftp: 5.1.3**

I have an inbound setup with `RotatingServerAdvice` that is watching two directories:

```
--inbox
-----dir1
-----dir2
```

Watching: `inbox/dir1` and `inbox/dir2`

Local directory: `temp/sftp`

When I put a file in `inbox/dir1/file1.txt`, my handler is called as expected and `file1.txt` is copied to a `temp/sftp/file1.txt` (<- this is the problem, details below)

**Problem:**

My use case is that when I get the file, I want to know which **remote subdirectory it's from**. If the local file was transferred to `temp/sftp/inbox/dir1/file1.txt` then I could tell that it came from `/inbox/dir1` and I can perform some operations on the remote sftp on this directory.

Why is the file being transferred flat and not in subdirectories on the local directory? Any help would be appreciated.

**Inbound Adapter:**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundsFlow(DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> delegatingSessionFactory,
    SftpServiceActivator serviceActivator) throws JSchException {

    SftpConnection config = sftpConnectionConfig.getSftpConnectionConfig(delegatingSessionFactory);

    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactory)
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .remoteDirectory("*")
                .filter(new CopartFileFilter(Pattern.compile(".*")))
                .localDirectory(new File( System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/" + config.getLocalDirectory())),
                e -> e.id("inboundSftpChannel")
                .autoStartup(true)
                .poller(Pollers
                    .fixedDelay(config.getPollerInterval())
                    .advice(advice(delegatingSessionFactory))
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
        .handle(m -> serviceActivator.handleMessage(m))
        .get();
}
```

File info on handler:

```
file: file1.txt, parent: /var/folders/sd/5k6jwzgs2hj2q165b6x9pql55mp8t7/T/sftp, headers {file_originalFile=/var/folders/sd/5k6jwzgs2hj2q165b6x9pql55mp8t7/T/sftp/file1.txt, id=d2620539-ab0d-2590-9b51-f4dfb442a74a, file_name=file1.txt, file_relativePath=file1.txt, timestamp=1581371879819}
```

**Try 1:**

I think this is similar to the first approach mentioned.

```
.localFilenameExpression("#remoteDirectory + '/' + #this")
```

It correctly puts the file under `temp/sftp/inbox/dir1/file1.txt`. The problem now is that the message I get is for this directory:

`temp/sftp/inbox`

Not the `file1.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had some trouble implementing the solutions suggested because of me being new to this. I went with a different approach because it worked fine for my requirement:

In the `sftpInboundsFlow`

```
.localFilenameExpression("#remoteDirectory.replaceAll('/', '-') + '_' + #this")
```

This places the files in a flat structure in the local temp directory.

```
 temp/sftp:
       inbox-dir1_file1.txt
```

Then in the handler:

1. Extract remote directory from file name:

   ```
   public String extractRemoteDir(File ackFile) {
       String fileName = ackFile.getName();
       return fileName.split("_")[0].replaceAll("-", "/");
   }
   ```
2. Custom logic on the remote dir
3. Delete ackFile

One thing that would make this less hacky would be to to know the remote directory in the local file handler (maybe in the headers), but I didn't find a way to find that.

Comment: would you please share your `advice()` method ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

Subclass the `StandardRotationPolicy`, overriding

```java
    @Override
    public void beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {

       ...

    }
```

Call `super.beforeReceive(source)` then cast the source to an `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource<?>`.

Then call `getCurrent()` to get the current `KeyDirectory`.

Then `abstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(...));`

Add your custom implementation to the advice.

However, you will have to use a `RecursiveDirectoryScanner` in the message source so the tree will be scanned.

Alternatively, use an outbound gateway configured to use the MGET command using alternate directories each time (or just `inbox` in recursive mode). The gateway can be configured to recreate the remote tree.

Comment: Can you check try 1? Any suggestions for this before I try the alternate approach of using outbound gateway?

Comment: I tried subclassing the StandardRotationPolicy but there is no method `source.getSynchronizer().setLocalDirectory`

Comment: Using the file name expression won't work because the second component (`FileReadingMessageSource`) doesn't know about the directory tree. Sorry, call `setLocalDirectory()` on the `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` after casting the source to it. (That's why I said "something like this" - I was answering from memory).

Comment: I just realized this won't work for the same reason; the `FileReadingMessageSource` will not know about the directory change. The gateway is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason why that happens. I'll look into how to setup a poller kind of a thing on the gateway.

Comment: It was late last night; there *is* a way to make it work - see the latest edit to my answer.

Comment: Any example of how to switch to `RecursiveDirectoryScanner`?

Comment: The DSL doesn't currently support modifying the scanner; you have to create the `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` as `@Bean` and set the `scanner` property. `RecursiveDirectoryScanner scanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
ms.setScanner(scanner);` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3175

Comment: You also can call `Sftp.inboundAdapter()...get()` and invoke the mentioned setter.

Comment: But don't do that inline in the flow definition - put that in a `@Bean` definition.